# In France, is it illicit to use a recorded content as a proof, when the person was recorded without knowing it?

Tags: france, recording

I remember hearing more than once from unofficial sources (and from people whose main domain isn't law) that you can't use a recording as a proof at the court, if said recording wasn't taken with the person's consent (or if it isn't a public area with some clear sign of recording devices, e.g. train stations for example).

For example: if I were to hide my phone in my back in recording mode, to record someone during a conversation, while they are saying something I could sue them for.

Now I know there are some cases of exception (e.g. if people are suspecting someone might be taking part to some terrorism acts for example, but that's the extreme case).

In what condition can a recording be considered as illegal, or otherwise, when is it legal to use a recorded material as a proof, even without consent of recording?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, this can land you in jail, no matter what**

In France, per [article 226-1 du code pénal](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070719&idArticle=LEGIARTI000006417929) recording without consent may be punished by one year in jail and 45000€ fine. Any recording without authorization of all parties involved (including the owners or administrators of buildings recorded either outside or inside due to copyright of the architectural image) can also land you in legal trouble either criminally or in civil court. The consent is implied if the parties involved knew about it and had means to deny authorization but didn't, but mind that any recording, secret or not, can be considered non consented, which probably discourage anyone from recording anything in France.

However you can still show these images obtained illegally in a court and the judge has the right to declare such recording justified (no statute about this, it is totally up to the judge) and thus allow you to use it as evidence both in civil or penal matters. It does not, however, protects you from being sued latter for the exposure of the recorded party, but the acceptance as evidence by a judge may serve as defense.

This means that many forms of recording in France, including tourists taking pictures of the Eiffel tower, obviously without authorization of the administrators of the tower or any potential passer-by, is in fact committing a crime, although obviously the law in simply not enforced for these cases. However, if a filmmaker records the Eiffel Tower and makes millions in box office, the tower administration will probably go to the trouble of collecting some money threatening to press charges if not paid.

Comment: How do you arrive at the part in parentheses in the first para? I see nothing there that implicate copyright in that article.

Comment: That one is something else I learned while I lived in France. It is not regulated by the law I mentioned.

Comment: The French law is really tricky in this matter, however, per statute, it is illegal to take random pictures of people or things in France without consent. But many people even after being sued got away with good sense by the judge.

Comment: Code de la propriété intellectuelle - Article L122-4 apparently answers your question. It does not allow even a sketch or translating a work without consent. Even the Eiffel Tower keyrings sold by the folks in the bottom of the tower can be illegal too (the sale without the permit being illegal already).

Comment: I had a small argument with someone who told me about pictures taken on the instant (I think he called that "clicher"). Usually, they are taken without the consent of the people around, and he'd pretend to not understand French when people told him not to take picture. When I told him about the laws you talked about there, he replied that French laws also allow you to take random pictures, because of which even famous people cannot file a lawsuit against paparazzi taking pictures of them. I wonder if it's worth opening another question, following up on this one...

Comment: @Clockwork Indeed they could file a lawsuit, but I guess that they just don't trouble themselves to avoid the Streissand effect.

Comment: There's a confusion between two things : yes, public buildings and certain private architectural works are protected by a sort of copyright, however taking pictures of *people*, even without their consent or awareness and even in private settings (provided you were not peeping and had the right to see what you photographed), is legal. The "droit à l'image" prevents *publishing* the pictures, not taking them.